# Wordpress native "playlist" shortcode. Next and Prev there are but with no icons. How to fix?

Tags: customization, audio, icon

If I use on my Wordpress 4.0 the beautiful playlist shortcode I don't see the famous "Next" and "Prev" icons, but only this code in my Html code:

`<div class="wp-playlist-next"></div>`

and

`<div class="wp-playlist-prev"></div>`

How to display icons to next and prev commands?

Answer (score 2):

in stylesheet:

```
.wp-playlist-prev{
   width:20px;
   height:20px;
   background-image: url("./theme_images_folder/something_icon.png");
}
```

*same for the next button.*

Comment: I've already tried this, but they appear under the bar of the audio. How do I get them to look at the side of the existing buttons, lessening the loading bar?

Answer (score 1):

To get them in the bar you could ignore the beautiful WP playlist ones and add your own using mediaelement.js directly, similar to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/154943/mediaelement-js-feature-doesnt-work).

You basically extend `MediaElementPlayer` by writing `buildXXX` functions, and then specify them in the settings `features` property as an array (along with all the other controls).

The following integrates them into WP by hooking the `wp_playlist_scripts` action with a priority of 9, early enough hopefully for the extensions of `MediaElementPlayer` and the WP `_wpmejsSettings` to kick in before the playlists get created by `wp-mediaelement`.

(For simplicity `dashicons` is used here for styling.)

```
add_action( 'wp_playlist_scripts', function () {
wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons' );
?>
<style>
.mejs-prev span, .mejs-next span {
    color:#eee; cursor:pointer; display:inline-block; font-family:"dashicons"; margin-top:5px;
}
</style>
<script>
(function ($) {
    if (typeof MediaElementPlayer !== 'undefined' && typeof _wpmejsSettings !== 'undefined') {
        $.extend(MediaElementPlayer.prototype, {
            buildprev: function(player, controls, layers, media) {
                var tracks = $('.wp-playlist-tracks .wp-playlist-item', controls.closest('.wp-playlist'));
                if (tracks.length > 1) {
                    $('<div class="mejs-button mejs-prev-button mejs-prev" >' +
                        '<span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-left-alt2" title="' + this.options.prevText + '"></span>' +
                    '</div>').appendTo(controls).on('click', function (event) {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        tracks.each(function (index) {
                            if ($(this).hasClass('wp-playlist-playing') ) {
                                index = (index - 1) % tracks.length;
                                tracks.get(index).click();
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            },
            buildnext: function(player, controls, layers, media) {
                var tracks = $('.wp-playlist-tracks .wp-playlist-item', controls.closest('.wp-playlist'));
                if (tracks.length > 1) {
                    $('<div class="mejs-button mejs-next-button mejs-next" >' +
                        '<span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt2" title="' + this.options.nextText + '"></span>' +
                    '</div>').appendTo(controls).on('click', function (event) {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        tracks.each(function (index) {
                            if ($(this).hasClass('wp-playlist-playing') ) {
                                index = (index + 1) % tracks.length;
                                tracks.get(index).click();
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        $.extend(_wpmejsSettings, {
            // Put these in the order you want.
            features: ['playpause','current','progress','duration','tracks','volume','fullscreen','prev','next'],
            prevText: <?php echo json_encode( __( 'Previous track' ) ); ?>,
            nextText: <?php echo json_encode( __( 'Next track' ) ); ?>
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
</script>
<?php
}, 9 );
```